# Function which takes a string as input and return another string after removing words that have characters repeated

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops, iterator

Write the function which takes a string as input and return another string after
removing words that have characters repeated like-

Input : "This is an example"
Output : "This is an"

```
def string_oper(string):
    if (len(string)==0):
        return ''
    if (set(string) == set(string[0])):
        return ''
    prev = None
    letters = [l for l in string]
    counter = 1
    new = []
    for l in letters:
        if l==prev:
            counter+=1
        else:
            if (counter==2):
                new.append(prev)
            counter=1
            new.append(l)
            prev = l
    return ''.join(new)

# and then you can do:

string= string.fillna('').map(string_oper)


if __name__=='__main__':

    string1 = input()
    print(string_oper(string1))
```

I am getting this error-

```
File "C:\Users\ptane\Downloads\Day3\week2-new.py", line 24, in <module>
    string= string.fillna('').map(string_oper)
            ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Comment: Did the `# and then you can do:` part come from? Was this part of the assignment text? It looks as though your function is meant to be used in an existing pandas dataframe called "string" (which is not a good name as it clashes with the `string`) module. You need to supply "string" - or perhaps take that line out completely.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove words from the string that have repeated characters (so `example` has two `e`, so remove it):

```py
def remove_words(s):
    return " ".join(word for word in s.split() if len(set(word)) == len(word))


s = "This is an example"
print(remove_words(s))
```

Prints:

```
This is an
```